# Upvotes on Area 51 example questions on proposals that get closed

Tags: support, area-51

What happens with upvotes from proposals that get closed on Area 51?

When I write questions in a proposal (Area 51) and get upvotes (reputation), and after a time this proposal gets closed, do I lose those upvotes?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you curious what happens to the rep of the people who wrote the questions? Please explain your question more thoroughly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been active on Area 51 in the past, and I don't think my reputation ever went down when a proposal was closed. However I did see questions from other people that did see a reputation decrease, e.g. [this post](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1628/48309).

I think reputation on Area 51 works the same as for other SE sites. If your post has reputation score of +3 or higher and is older than 60 days, then deletion doesn't decrease your reputation ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/164138)).